# MySQL not detected in Amazon ec2 user LAMP

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Im using Amazon Web Service

Im using Amazon ec2-user LAMPP

Im using PHP 5.6

Im using Laravel 4.2

Last week it was working properly, but now when i get back, its not working anymore. Is this about the version?

```
[root@ip-270-30-3-280 ec2-user]# sudo yum update -y
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                                                                                   | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest                                                                                                | 2.3 kB     00:00     
rpmforge                                                                                                           | 1.9 kB     00:00     
571 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No packages marked for update
[root@ip-270-30-3-280 ec2-user]# sudo yum install -y httpd24 php56 mysql55-server php56-mysqlnd
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
571 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Package httpd24-2.4.12-1.60.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package php56-5.6.8-1.111.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package mysql55-server-5.5.42-1.4.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package php56-mysqlnd-5.6.8-1.111.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@ip-270-30-3-280 ec2-user]# mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
[root@ip-270-30-3-280 ec2-user]#
```

i have already mysql server setup and php, 
but im having this trouble ab`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)`

how do i connect Mysql server to its proper socket?

Comment: You have MySQL server installed but not running. Try `sudo service mysqld start`

Comment: `Starting mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]`
its still giving me the error `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
`

Answer (score 0):

Some of points to look at:

- check once again `service mysqld status`
- ensure that socket file is set correctly in `my.cnf` and permissions are set correctly to `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`

Comment: but im doing this in amazon server, its online. do i really have to use 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @MarlonBuendia sorry, might be misleading. Have you checked the status/permissions?

Comment: havent check it.. last month it was working, i leave it for a month when i get back its not working anymore.

Comment: Try to restart MySQL: `/etc/init.d/mysql restart` or `service mysql restart`